# Building a Media Player in React Native expo and Getting duration of song

Tags: react-native, audio, expo

I am implementing a Media player in React Native expo. I have designed my player, play song, next and previous songs functionality but I am having an issue getting the duration of the song, in order to be able to display the progress of the song using a progress bar.

I have gone through https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/ and didn't find anything on how to get the duration of the file or how to get any information that can help me in the progress bar implementation. Any ideas are highly welcome.

The code I'm experimenting with:

```js
// Create new object from Expo.Audio.Sound
   this.soundObject = new Audio.Sound();
   await this.soundObject.loadAsync(url);
   await this.soundObject.playAsync();


   getCurrentItemArtistName = ()=> {
        return this.list[this.index].artistname;
    };

   getCurrentItemCover = ()=> {
        return this.list[this.index].cover;
    };
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Have you got this so far? And is the expo audio working fine for you?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you still interested, however, as follow a way to **get the duration**.

```
const sound = new Audio.Sound();

try {

   const track = await sound.loadAsync(require('../../models/smw_bonus_game_end.mp3'));

   console.log(track.durationMillis); // Prints the duration in milliseconds

  } catch (err) {
   console.log(err);
  };
```

You can get the duration **after you have loaded the file**.

---

**Additional information can be found in the object**. Using the same code below, just try to print only the const *track*:

```
console.log(track);
```

It will print an object as follow:

```
 Object {
  "didJustFinish": false,
  "durationMillis": 3108,
  "hasJustBeenInterrupted": false,
  "isBuffering": false,
  "isLoaded": true,
  "isLooping": false,
  "isMuted": false,
  "isPlaying": false,
  "pitchCorrectionQuality": "Varispeed",
  "playableDurationMillis": 3108,
  "positionMillis": 0,
  "progressUpdateIntervalMillis": 500,
  "rate": 1,
  "shouldCorrectPitch": false,
  "shouldPlay": false,
  "uri": "THE URI OF THE FILE IN YOUR DEVICE",
  "volume": 1,
}
```

Many other information are available, let me know if you need something specific.

I hope this helps!

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. But it was used within a `Sound` class component.

```
CurrentDuration = async () => {
        const Mill = await this.soundObject.getStatusAsync();
        let p = Mill.positionMillis;
    return {curr:p};
  };
```